# How to structure nested resources - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested

In my Rails 4 app, an `admin` can moderate/approve `posts`, `user accounts`, and `photos`.  I already have controllers for each of these (`PostsController`, `UsersController`, `PhotosController`) that handle the basic CRUD operations initiated by the user.

Having the `update` method for each controller seems incorrect and ...  dirty.  So does creating a single `ModerationController` with non-RESTful methods for each of the models.

I think I need something like a `ModeratePostsController` for each of the models, but I'm not sure how that gets scoped (under `/admin`?) or nested in `routes.rb` and generated as a controller.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was pretty much there.

I ran `rails g controller Admin::Posts` to create `/app/controllers/admin/posts_controller.rb` and in the routes file I added:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :teams
end
```